Getting a property value from a Kotlin Object via a name string
I'm working on a Kotlin project where I need to collect errors resulting from an API call and return them to the user in a readable format. The API call will return a JSON string containing the error message and the field_name of the request data that caused the error. Note that this is a third party API so I have no control over the returned json format. What I want to do is take this field_name string and use it to extract the corresponding value of the request data object to build a user friendly error message.
My request class looks like:
data class Request(val parent_identifier: String?=null, val display_name: String)

So if I do something like:
val req = Request("abc", "123")
val errorJson = callAPI(req)
//{"index":2,"message":"Identifier can not be matched.","field_name":"parent_identifier"}
val propertyName = errorJson.field_name
//"parent_identifier"

How can I extract the value from req to produce an error like:

"Update failed: parent_identifier 'abc' could not be matched."

Is it possible to do this without the kotlin reflect
library?
If not, how do I use kotlin reflect to extract a property value using a name string? Also how much of a performance penalty will I suffer for using reflection?

How about deserialising the JSON?

@Sweeper I'm not quite sure how that would help. What json would I deserialize and how would that get me the property value?

You deserialise the JSON returned by callAPI. You would then be able to write errorJson.field_name directly. Declare a serialisable class with a property called field_name - that will be the type of errorJson.

I think you are misunderstanding the issue. Turning the results of the API call into an object is not the problem. The issue is that I need to get a specific value from the Request object, but the field is not known at runtime. I need a way to retrieve the value dynamically based on the value of the 'field_name' supplied by the response error. So yes, deserializing the response will give me the field name string, but I still need a way to extract the corresponding value from Request.

Ah I see what you mean now. I have indeed misunderstood the issue.

You can do this by creating a map of property names to their corresponding values in your Request class.
 data class Request(val parent_identifier: String? = null, val display_name: String)
    
    fun main() {
        val req = Request("abc", "123")
        val errorJson = "{\"index\":2,\"message\":\"Identifier can not be matched.\",\"field_name\":\"parent_identifier\"}"
        val propertyName = getErrorMessage(req, errorJson)
        println(propertyName)
    }
    
    fun getErrorMessage(req: Request, errorJson: String): String {
        val errorMap = mapOf(
            "parent_identifier" to req.parent_identifier,
            "display_name" to req.display_name
        )
    
        val errorObject = parseErrorJson(errorJson)
        val fieldName = errorObject["field_name"] ?: return "Unknown field name"
        val value = errorMap[fieldName] ?: return "Unknown property value for $fieldName"
    
        return "Update failed: $fieldName '$value' could not be matched."
    }
    
    fun parseErrorJson(json: String): Map<String, Any> {
        //implement the logic to parse the JSON string into a Map
       
        val map = mutableMapOf<String, Any>()
       
        return map
    }


I may end up falling back to that solution but it is not ideal. The actual Request data class is more complex than the simple example I gave here.
